# pdftotext-buildpack is not getting installed on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, buildpack, pdftotext

**I am getting this when deploying my python app.**

```
remote: -----> pdftotext-buildpack app detected
remote: -----> pdftotext-buildpack: Installed to app/bin
remote: -----> nginx-buildpack app detected
remote: -----> nginx-buildpack: Installed nginx/1.9.5 to app/bin
remote: -----> nginx-buildpack: Added start-nginx to app/bin
remote: -----> nginx-buildpack: Added start-nginx-solo to app/bin
remote: -----> nginx-buildpack: Default mime.types copied to 
app/config/
remote: -----> nginx-buildpack: Default config copied to app/config.
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> release, web
```

**but getting following error when i am trying to access pdftotext**

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or 
directory:`/app/bin/pdftotext`
```

Comment: it's installed in app/bin and you are looking for it in usr/bin

Comment: @VaibhavVishal I have checked its not there as well

Comment: I solved it. The build-pack was not added successfully.